# Fine Uploader generates incorrect StringToSign against nonstandard service endpoint

Tags: fine-uploader

We are using Fine Uploader in S3 mode against a non-traditional, though S3-compliant, service. It uses an unusual hostname and port. The /signature/ endpoint gets called with a payload like this:

{"headers":"POST\n\nimage/jpeg\n\nx-amz-acl:private\nx-amz-date:Tue, 05 Aug 2014 20:28:11 GMT\nx-amz-meta-qqfilename:Pomegranate.jpg\n/service-fqdn.com/37b5165cf4fd.jpg?uploads"}

In other words, Fine is (quite reasonably) treating this like a CNAME style virtual hosted bucket and generating the StringToSign accordingly. In fact, service-fqdn.com is a service endpoint to itself, and the canonical resource named in the StringToSign should be simply:

/bucketname/37b5165cf4fd.jpg?uploads

In this configuration, bucketname is provided on the path, not as part of the domain name.

Manually patching the incoming StringToSign inside the /signature/ endpoint results in a successful upload.

So what is the proper way to configure Fine Uploader to understand that service-fqdn.com is a service endpoint? [For comparison, in the common s3curl.pl utility, one needs to modify the source code with a list of known endpoints.]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader S3 currently expects that all endpoints are actual S3 buckets.  There is a plan to update the S3 code to allow uploads to work seamlessly with any service that "acts like" an S3 endpoint.  Part of that effort involves [allowing uploads to a CloudFront distribution](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1016).  Some internal discussion suggests that we will address the CF distro feature in such a way that uploads to any S3-like endpoint will work as a result.

Until then, as you have stated, the logic used to determine the bucket name will need to be tweaked.

As a side note, unless I am misremembering, I believe we have spoken about your specific use case via email.  If I am correct, I would encourage you to bring this up in the email thread started back in July.